# Setting GridView column width on runtime when data is bound from a sql source

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I'm facing problem in setting GridView columns width when data is bound from SQL source. I've tested the code without binding data from SQL source and it works perfectly. I'm pasting both (with & without SQL source) codes here for you to better understand the problem. 
I'd start from "Without binding data from SQL source". 
GridView code (.aspx):

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="true" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" CellPadding="4" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
            <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" PageButtonCount="10" Position="Bottom" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="link" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Num1") %>' Text="Test" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Code behind (.cs) is:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    namespace Sample_project_to_set_column_width_of_a_gridview
    {
       public partial class form1 : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {            
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    Bind();
                }                   
            }

            protected void Bind()
            {
                 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                 DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Num1", typeof(string));
                 DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("Num2", typeof(string));
                 DataColumn dc3 = new DataColumn("Num3", typeof(string));
                 DataColumn dc4 = new DataColumn("Num4", typeof(string));
                 dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
                 dt.Columns.Add(dc2);
                 dt.Columns.Add(dc3);
                 dt.Columns.Add(dc4);
                 DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                 dr["Num1"] = "AAA";
                 dr["Num2"] = "BBBFFFF";
                 dr["Num3"] = "AAASSSSS";
                 dr["Num4"] = "BBBFFHHHF";

                 DataRow dr2 = dt.NewRow();
                 dr2["Num1"] = "CCC";
                 dr2["Num2"] = "DDDFFFFF";
                 dr2["Num3"] = "CCC";
                 dr2["Num4"] = "DDDFFFFF";

                 dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                 dt.Rows.Add(dr2);
                 GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                 GridView1.DataBind();

            }

            protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[0].Width = 100;
                    e.Row.Cells[0].Style["border-right"] = "2px solid #666666";
                    e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.CornflowerBlue;

                    e.Row.Cells[1].Width = 200;
                    e.Row.Cells[1].Style["border-right"] = "2px solid #666666";
                    e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.CornflowerBlue;

                    e.Row.Cells[2].Width = 400;
                    e.Row.Cells[2].Style["border-right"] = "2px solid #666666";
                    e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Lime;

                    e.Row.Cells[3].Width = 600;
                    e.Row.Cells[3].Style["border-right"] = "2px solid #666666";
                    e.Row.Cells[3].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

                    e.Row.Cells[4].Width = 800;
                    e.Row.Cells[4].Style["border-right"] = "2px solid #666666";
                    e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Above code works perfectly. Here is [a link](http://oi62.tinypic.com/2vinuon.jpg) to see the desired output. 
Now when I bind data to GridView through SQL source, I don't get to see the desired results. Modified codebehind file (.cs) code is:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    namespace Sample_project_to_set_column_width_of_a_gridview
    {
        public partial class form1 : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Bind();
            }
        }

        protected void Bind()
        {
             SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MEHDI-PC\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=PIMS; Integrated Security=true;");
              {
                  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                  {
                      String sql = "select * from dbo.Documents";
                      cmd.Connection = con;
                      cmd.CommandText = sql;
                      con.Open();
                      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                      using (SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                      {
                          adp.Fill(ds);
                      }
                      GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                      GridView1.DataBind();
                  }
              }
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[0].Width = 100;
                e.Row.Cells[0].Style["border-right"] = "2px solid #666666";
                e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.CornflowerBlue;

                e.Row.Cells[1].Width = 200;
                e.Row.Cells[1].Style["border-right"] = "2px solid #666666";
                e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.CornflowerBlue;

                e.Row.Cells[2].Width = 400;
                e.Row.Cells[2].Style["border-right"] = "2px solid #666666";
                e.Row.Cells[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Lime;

                e.Row.Cells[3].Width = 600;
                e.Row.Cells[3].Style["border-right"] = "2px solid #666666";
                e.Row.Cells[3].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

                e.Row.Cells[4].Width = 800;
                e.Row.Cells[4].Style["border-right"] = "2px solid #666666";
                e.Row.Cells[4].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output that I get by running this SQL bound data can be accessed [here](http://oi62.tinypic.com/2hxxabo.jpg).

Can anyone notice a reason why I can't set width when binding from SQL source. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't show images. Show the HTML. Does the HTML look like you want?

Comment: @JotaBe HTML is showing Column width as correct but not properly laying it in the browser.

Comment: So the HTML is good, and the styles are good, but you don't get what you want. I.e. the width is set in the HTML but not respected?

Comment: @JotaBe That's correct.

Comment: @JotaBe Any workaround?

Comment: @JotaBe I worked it out. Thanks for your hint.

Comment: Glad to know it. The learnt lesson is: always look at the HTML, not at the visual appearance. If you had directly shown the HTML it would have been easier to further help you.

Comment: By the way, it would be great if you posted an answer and accepted it yourself to share with other people. That's usual in SO.

Answer (score 0):

you can set width for gridview like this

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    { 
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
         e.Row.Cells[1].Width = 1;
         e.Row.Cells[0].Width = 1;
         e.Row.Cells[4].Width = 75;
         e.Row.Cells[5].Width = 1;                
}
    }
```

another option through .aspx page

```
<Columns>

<asp:BoundField DataField="" HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="5%" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" />

<asp:BoundField DataField="" HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="25%" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" />

<asp:BoundField DataField="" HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="30%"

ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="" />

<asp:BoundField DataField="" HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="25%" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" />

<asp:BoundField DataField="" HeaderText="" ItemStyle-Width="10%"

ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" />

</Columns>
```

Comment: Your code runs without an error but Cell's width is not being set. For e.g., `e.Row.Cells[4].Width = 75;` is giving same output as `e.Row.Cells[4].Width = 500;` which means `Width` is not being read by the browser when binding data from SQL. Thanks

Comment: Internet Explorer, Google Chrome.

Comment: I am binding data from SQL source. For that I have to set AutoGenerateColumn as True. If I use BoundField, I will have to change whole lot of code.